# Change layer of UI object UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have some pics on the Page that I can move and I need change layer on the selected image(e.g. double tap or long press)

```
<Image x:Name="CollageImg1" Margin="1076,464,959,805" Source="{Binding CollageImg1}" ManipulationDelta="CollageImgage1_Manipulation">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
         <CompositeTransform/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

All images have similar code

Comment: What you mean by layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved.

I need change 
'ZIndex'. Example: 'Canvas.SetZIndex(xamlImage,(int)layerNumber);'